# what is ''equivalence'' in fortran77 MatLab Counterpart

Tags: matlab, fortran77

what is ''equivalence'' in fortran77 MatLab Counterpart for example:

```
integer a,b
equivalence(a,b)
a=2
write(*,I5),b
```

this program allocate same place of memory for a and b
if any one of them change,other one also change.

WHAT is the MatLab Counterpart code ?

Comment: Please reformat your code to be more readable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Based on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn9b/index.html) documentation, `equivalence` finds variables that are sharing the same memory? matlab is a very high-level language and does not have anything like this. Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish in matlab?

Comment: Instead of transcoding, did you consider simply compiling your fortran code to a mex-function?